# Questions about a step on Morera’s theorem + a possible modification of the assumptions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

1. I’m trying to understand why the function $ F(z)=\int _{\gamma }f(\zeta )d\zeta$ used in [Wikipedia’s proof of Morera’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) satisfies $F′(z) = f(z)$ (I’ve already understood why it’s well defined, that is, why it depends only on the endpoints of $\gamma$). The Wikipedia article just says that this can be proven “by using the continuity of $f$ to estimate difference quotients”, but doesn’t provide any more details, and I don’t see at all what they mean.
2. I also have a follow-up question: the Wikipedia article mentions that ”the assumption of Morera's theorem is equivalent to $f$ locally having an antiderivative on $D$” (this is the point I’m trying to understand in general). This is the assumption of the theorem:

> Morera's theorem states that a continuous, complex-valued function $f$
> defined on an open set D in the complex plane that satisfies
>
> $$ \oint _{\gamma }f(z)dz=0$$
>
> for every closed piecewise $C^1$ curve $\gamma$ in $D$ must be
> holomorphic on $D$.

My follow-up question is, if we changed the conditions from $\gamma$ being a piecewise $C^1$ curve to $\gamma$ being a concatenation of directed (piecewise) $C^2$ curves $\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\}$, would this modified version of the assumption of Morera’s theorem be equivalent to $f$ locally having an antiderivative on $D$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2.)$ The weakest form of this theorem is when the $\gamma$ are restricted to triangular contours, which are piecewise $C^\infty$. If, for all such $\gamma$, we have: $$\oint_\gamma f=0$$Then that is equivalent to $f$ having local antiderivatives.

$(1.)$ The argument to show $F'(z)=f(z)$ is standard and very similar to the proof of the same in real analysis.

Let $U$ be an open set in which $F:z\mapsto\int_{z_0}^zf$ is well defined. Fix $z\in U$. For $h$ small enough that $z+h\in U$ (a neighbourhood of such $h$ around zero exists by openness) we know:

$$|F(z+h)-F(z)-h\cdot f(z)|=\left|\int_z^{z+h}(f(s)-f(z))\,\mathrm{d}s\right|\le\sup_{s\in\gamma(I)}|f(s)-f(z)|\cdot\ell(\gamma)$$Where the integral $z\to z+h$ is parametrised by $\gamma$ and $\ell$ denotes length. Taking open balls, we can always arrange these $\gamma$ to be straight line contours since open balls are convex. Fixing an open ball of radius $\delta$, we can bound $\sup|f(s)-f(z)|$ uniformly among all such contours contained in the open ball when $\delta$ is sufficiently small - by continuity of $f$ - and $\ell(\gamma)=h$. Thus: $$\limsup_{h\to0}\left|\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)-h\cdot f(z)}{h}\right|$$Can be made arbitrarily small by picking small $\delta$: thus, $F'(z)=f(z)$.